# Cmake cant find boost which installed from source in CentOS 7

Tags: cmake, centos7, cmake-modules

I installed boost from the source file in `CentOS7`, I do these steps :

- wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz
- tar -xzf boost_1_*
- cd boost_1_*
- ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost
- ./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all

I checked and all file was correctly in `/opt/boost/lib`

[image]

then I want to compile my project but CMake couldn't find the correct version of boost :

I compile it whit this command :

```
cmake -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/boost/lib/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

**I got this Error :**

> CMake Error at
> /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2048 (message):
> Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.53.0
>
> Boost include path: /usr/include
>
> Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.67
> (or   newer). Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:13
> (FIND_PACKAGE)

what should I do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots for error messages that can be easily copy-pasted as code. It makes your question inaccessible to search engines and people with visual impairments that have to rely on screen reader technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try and specify the include and library directories directly, instead, give the root directory (sometimes called *installation prefix*) as a hint to the find call.

You currently do `-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/boost/lib/`, but `/opt/boost/lib` does not actually contain any header files, so it's not a valid include directory, but rather the library directory. While it is possible to specify both library and include directories explicitly, doing so is fiddly and error-prone and therefore not recommended.

Instead you should provide the *root directory* for the library. When installing the library you will eventually end up with a directory structure like this:

```
/opt
  + boost
     + include
       + <all header files in here>
     + lib
       + <all library (.a and .so) files in here>
```

The root directory is the directory that contains both the include and library directories, so in this case it would be `/opt/boost`.

In CMake versions 3.12 and higher, `find_package` considers the [`<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html#variable:%3CPackageName%3E_ROOT) and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` system environment variable as search hints. Additionally, the [Boost find script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#hints) that ships with CMake supports the `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOSTROOT` CMake variables as search hints since pretty much forever.

So your command line really should look like this:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/boost -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

If that still doesn't work, it most probably means that you're dealing with a non-standard directory layout. Consult the documentation for the [`FindBoost` script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) to figure out how to pass additional hints for such a situation, but really, I would strongly recommend to switch the directory layout instead.